# making SAX parser process a DOM tree

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax

I've got a DOM tree I want to receive `org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler` callbacks from it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be support for this in the [Transformer API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/package-summary.html), by using a [DOMSource](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/dom/DOMSource.html) and a [SAXResult](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/sax/SAXResult.html)

Answer (score 0):

A SAX parser parses an XML document into a stream; a DOM parser parses an XML document into a tree. You've got an already-parsed document, so presumably you also have the underlying document. You can of course reparse that.

Comment: maybe I've built a DOM tree at run-time and I want to process it using SAX callbacks because I've already got working code for that?